# Python server.sendmail() returns {}. Email not sent

Tags: python, email, sendmail, smtplib

I'm having a file.txt file which has many lines. I want that any one line is chosen at random and emailed. This is looped thrice.

```
import smtplib,datetime,random

def mail(em):
    #print "yo"
    fromAddress = "atadmorecouth@gmail.com"
    toAddress = "atadmorecouth@gmail.com"
    subject = "WOW " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    #print subject
    msg = em
    server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    password = "mypassword"
    server.login(fromAddress, password)
    server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddress, msg)
    #print server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddress, msg)


for i in range(0,3):
    em=str(random.choice(list(open('file.txt'))))
    mail(em)
```

This code does not work. The login and everything is fine. The only problem I notice is that server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddress, msg) returns an empty {}
What could be the possible fix to this? Whats the problem in first place?
I have run the mail() function in the terminal and that seems to work fine. 
All the files are hosted [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13074887557444716748)

Comment: why you posted your password ????

Comment: It's _supposed_ to return an empty `{}`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail): "If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused." So, this means that you had no errors.

Comment: @Geez! I forgot to change that in the script. Anyways, its not an important account as such

Comment: Editing out your password isn't going to help; it's still available in the history of this question. Go change your password immediately—and if you've used the same password anywhere else, change it there too.

Comment: Meanwhile, please add `server.setdebuglevel(1)`, as shown in the example from the docs, and post the results here.

Comment: @abarnert: Done, And this password was a dummy one used nowhere. Anyways, Password has been changed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) say:

> If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused.

So, the fact that you're getting back `{}` isn't a problem; it means that you had no errors.

---

Second, what you're sending is not a valid message. A message must contain headers, then a blank line, then the body. And the headers should contain at least `From:` and `To:`.

The `smtplib` library doesn't do this for you; as explained in [the example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example):

> Note that the headers to be included with the message must be included in the message as entered; this example doesn’t do any processing of the RFC 822 headers. In particular, the ‘To’ and ‘From’ addresses must be included in the message headers explicitly.
>
> ...
>
> **Note**: In general, you will want to use the `email` package’s features to construct an email message, which you can then convert to a string and send via `sendmail()`; see [*email: Examples*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples).

Or, in the [`sendmail`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) docs:

> **Note**: The `from_addr` and `to_addrs` parameters are used to construct the message envelope used by the transport agents. The SMTP does not modify the message headers in any way.

In this case (as in the example), it's simple enough to just craft the message manually:

```
msg = "From: {}\r\nTo: {}\r\n\r\n{}\r\n".format(fromAddress, toAddress, em)
```

---

Finally, you really should call [`server.quit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.quit) at the end of the `mail` function. While (at least in CPython) the `server` object will be destroyed as soon as the function ends, unlike many other objects in Python, `SMTP` objects do not call `close` when destroyed, much less `quit`. So, from the server's point of view, you're suddenly dropping connection. While the RFCs suggest that a server *should* work just fine without a `QUIT`, and most of them do, they also recommend that the client should always send it and wait for a response, so… why not do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: python `server.sendmail()` **returned {} but email was not sent**. However, the accepted answer did not help in my specific case. Eventually, I figured why: for me, the underlying problem was not the message headers, but the fact that the address of the sender had a typo!

Example to reproduce the problem:

```py
import smtplib

fromAddress = 'wrong_address_with_typo_or_invalid'
toAddress = 'wrong_address_with_typo_or_invalid'

msg = "From: {}\r\nTo: {}\r\n\r\n{}\r\n".format(fromAddress, toAddress, 'Hello!')

server = smtplib.SMTP('some.domain.com')
server.sendmail(fromAddress, toAddress, msg)
```

This returns `{}`. It does not trigger any error. Somewhat surprisingly, it does not trigger exceptions: neither [SMTPSenderRefused](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused) nor [SMTPRecipientsRefused](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused), which is odd to me because [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) says that SMTPSenderRefused is raised when

> The server didn’t accept the from_addr.

I guess, the server I used accepts whatever string as email address, effectively masking any problem due to sender's address.